# In $C([0,1])$ is it true that if $f_n\to f$, iff $f_n\to f$ uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis

In $C([0,1])$ (the set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, if we have the metric $$d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$$ is it true that $f_n\to f$ if and only if $f_n\to f$ uniformly?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Yes.  You should think of convergence in sup norms as what uniform convergence really is.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, for the expression $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$, for all $n\geq N$ and for all $x\in[0,1]$, one can take $\sup$ with respect to $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ (with $n$ fixed) for $x\in[0,1]$ to get $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\leq\epsilon$, so $d(f_{n},f)\leq\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$.

Answer (score 0):

With this metric, yes. With this metric you define uniform convergence on $[0,1]$.